# How to check multitouch in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, xorg

I have several questions about multitouch in Linux:

1. Is multitouch and MPX (multi-pointer extension) related? If an application handles multiple cursors does it mean that it is multitouch-ready?
2. How to test if multitouch is really working

   1. In the system (Xorg, drivers)
   2. In the given application
3. How to test/develop for multitouch if I don't have a multitouch device? Can I simulate it somehow?
4. How to test that html5 multitouch support is working? Should I, for example, use [this](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/canvasphoto/) demo?

**Update 1:**

[2.1] To see if multitouch is supported in drivers one can dump /dev/input/eventX and see whether it has multitouch-related events (like `0x2f /*MT slot being modified*/` or `0x35    /* Center X ellipse position */`): `hd /dev/input/event... | grep ' 00  03 00 2f'`
[3] Started simple [touchscreen simulator](https://github.com/vi/virtual_touchscreen). May be there is already one somewhere?

**Update 2:**

According to `xinput test 6` I see the multitouch events. But in `xev` output I see only repeated MotionEvents without additional coordinates for multitouch. XInput2 data also does not contain any multitouch-related...

Comment: 1) Multitouch and MPX is related. 2) There are many online DIY kits online to create a multitouch environment. I think nuigroup.com is a good starting point. 3) Question 2 answers this too. There are small scale and large scale devices. 4) research

Comment: Note: I've already developed my own solution to `3.`: https://github.com/vi/virtual_touchscreen

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that multitouch or MPX imply multiple cursors - there will still only be one. Multitouch basically means that the system can handle more than one input at a time (multiple fingers for example). I think that MPX supports that. This allows you to touch two fingers, draw them together, and if programmed appropriately, the system will shrink the image accordingly. This all requires GUI support software. It doesn't happen auto-magically.